# How can I get continuity of Messages if I'm not using Migration Assistant?

Tags: macos, messages

I manually copied `~/Library/Messages` from my old Macbook to my new Macbook.

Yet `Messages` still does not see the message history.

How can I get continuity of Messages if I'm not using Migration Assistant?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Messages in iCloud on both Macs?

Comment: @Thinkr You're right. Apple really wants us to use iCloud, even for (phone) text messages and media. And this is just a first step before moving iTunes music and photos (Photos) manually. Will those also not work using a simple folder copying?

Comment: I think you will have to use iCloud Drive to move, copy, and sync folders between your devices. But enabling iCloud for Messages will sync your messages on all devices connected to the same Apple ID. No need to pay a subscription or anything to use iCloud for Messages. Just make sure you are connected to the same Apple ID on both your old and your new Mac.

Comment: @Thinkr Actually Apple includes 5GB of iCloud with your AppleId. I am paying for more. Still, for sizeable data (photo collection, ..), and even for Messages, I wish we'd be given the option of using the 3.5GB/s Thunderbolt speed that we get on modern hardware.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean. I don't think this is possible (as you may have already noticed). Maybe try to contact Apple Support to let you know if it's possible or not. ;)

Comment: Any success with the "Enable Messages in iCloud" idea?

Comment: @paws No. It was a pretty lousy experience. I had to create a new account on Ventura, logging in with the same AppleId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not manually copy
`~/Library/Messages` from an old Mac to a new Mac.

Weird effects will ensue, such as being able to text some recipients from either iPhone or macOS and see the messages simultaneously appear in the other OS/device (as expected), but seeing the dreaded

[image: message has not been sent]

when you attempt to text from macOS for *some* recipients. Those recipients remain reachable, but only through iOS.